# match-3, 4, 5, 6? Algorithm for a puzzle match game that will change the number of matches required

Tags: algorithm, ai, puzzle

I was wondering if someone had an idea or had some thoughts behind creating a match-3, match-4, match-5... all the way to match-10 just by changing a variable.

I think it is easy to do a match 3 or 4, but with higher matches, it becomes difficult and a new algorithm is needed. Does anyone have an idea on how this would be implemented?

I'm totally stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Ummm... Sorry but what? I don't even understand the question.

Comment: so, in many match 3 games you need to match 3 gems next to each other like bejeweled. 

In a match 4, you need to match 4 gems that are touching each other (any of tetris block formations). 

match5 is 5 gems, etc.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant by matching games. Sorry, to me a matching game could be anything from Bejeweled to Memory so I wasn't sure what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Just keep it as a variable, i.e. `numToMatch = 3`. In your algorithm, refer to this variable exclusively when you're trying to determine if there's a match or not.

If you want to vary this, say from level to level, I would suggest some algorithm like breadth-first or depth-first search, where you note the amount of touching, matched tiles. If it reaches the number you want, boom, victory.